# JSON.NET Deserializing a JSON into a dictionary comes back as null

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "AAPL": { "price": "131.85000" },
  "eur/usd": { "price": "1.06290" },
  "msft": { "price": "238.76000" }
}
```

When I try to deserialize this into a dictionary it comes back as null.

I am using the TwelveDataAPI.
https://twelvedata.com/docs#real-time-price

I have tried creating a simple class that will allow me to deserialize this JSON even if there are different tickers and different amounts of them.

My class:

```cs
public class CurrentPriceClass
{
    public class Root
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Price> Prices { get; set; }
    }

    public class Price
    {
        public string price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But when I try to deserialize it, it comes back as `null`, and I cannot iterate over it:

```cs
CurrentPriceClass.Root priceRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CurrentPriceClass.Root>(
dataJson);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, CurrentPriceClass.Price> price in priceRoot.Prices)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{price.Key}: {price.Value.price}");
}
```

The error I get when iterating is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When debugging `priceRoot` is `null`.
I am assuming that this is a problem with my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deserialize as `Dictionary<string, CurrentPriceClass.Price>` without needing the root class (`CurrentPriceClass`).

```cs
Dictionary<string, CurrentPriceClass.Price> priceRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, CurrentPriceClass.Price>>(dataJson);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, CurrentPriceClass.Price> price in priceRoot)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{price.Key}: {price.Value.price}");
}
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qrPrRF)